# React & Headless Drupal 8

Tags: reactjs, drupal-8

I am having trouble finding a value in a json response! I have setup a headless drupal api with a React front end. The problem I am having is that the React script is not able to find the 'title' value in the json array. The function that is failing is the componentDidMount(). I have the js code below and the json response. Thank you for the help

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
    title: ''
  }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
 this.serverRequest = axios.get(this.props.source).then(event =>{    
       this.setState({
            title: event.data[0].attributes.title.value
        });
   });
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   this.serverRequest.abort();
 }

 render() {
   return (
       <div>
           <h1>Here is a blog entry:</h1>
           <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
       </div>
   ); 
  }
 }

 ReactDOM.render(
   <App source="http://terra-blog.dd:8083/jsonapi/node/blog" />, 
   document.getElementById('test')
 );
```

JSON response

[image]

ERROR in console

[image]

Comment: No worries I got it ; ) if there is a better way to do this let me know..